# Reading SIM data via file managers using USB datamodem

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb, modem, mobile

How to browse a GSM SIM card's filesystem in Linux / nautilus / pcmanfm filemanager, and read the files with suitable editors ?

There is one related post: [Howto read SMS stored on a SIM card?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28372/howto-read-sms-stored-on-a-sim-card) But this is related to reading the card via mobiles and synching it with computers.

Could you direct me to appropriate links please?

I have already read the link: [How to access a SIM card programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792354/how-to-access-a-sim-card-programatically)

The post contains no link related to my issue. The links are on different issue, useful for Windows computers. I use Linux systems only

The SIM card is inserted into my Huawei USB datamodem e1731. Can I read it from there? I do not wish to buy a SIM card reader.

Further, while researching about various linux packages that could potentially do this I came across the following:

- comex
- Monosim
- SIM_Brush
- google_talk
- minicom
- pysim_reader
- wammu_gammu

I tried with `minicom`, but failed to make much headway.

I have not read about anyone who has implemented these packages with success.

My ultimate plan is to use the USB-datacard I have to make and receive phone calls using a close-talk microphone, and read and write SMSes. I posted my idea in the Debian and Knoppix forums, but have not heard anything positive.

[If Mobile-> Internet access Modem, why not datacard->mobile](http://knoppix.net/forum/threads/30533-If-Mobile-Internet-access-Modem-why-not-datacard-mobile-with-laptop-n-mic-hdphone?p=129079#post129079)

[Voice call with softmodem, tel_Line & close-talk headset](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=105510)

[If Mobile-> Internet access Modem, why not datacard->mobile](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=103013)

[Is voice call possible through USBmodem with minicom?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163528)

Then there is also Asterisk and Amatisoft. Since I have very little bandwidth at present I can't experiment with these packages. I have Knoppix and I could experiment with it (that way I ensure that my system is not damaged while experimenting), had I some bandwidth. I have just about enough to read and write emails and posts in forums.

I have had a detailed discussion with Amatisoft when I requested the company to have the live CD file released via rsync or torrent file. The company said that it does not wish to compromise security running rsync in their server. The company has remained mum on the torrent file. In the meanwhile, the amatixoffice was downloaded with kget last month, but the file is corrupt (minor). Had there been rsync running in their servers I would have had no difficulty in downloading the minor correction, and not the entire file once again! The same logic applies with bittorrent server.

I was even contacted by one person from Portugal who wanted me to install and test the PBX system in tandem with him, but I could not help him because of the corrupt file that I have from Amatisoft.

I did huge research last month, but the bandwidth issue is a dampener. Please read this page: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Install+CDROM
Again, my limited bandwidth is not allowing me to research further.

I also researched on servers that allow remote upload and syncing, the potential candidates being those listed in the Wikipedia, and these companies were sent emails. My idea was to upload the amatisoft file remotely and then repair the erroneous portion of the file in my download directory.  It is found that none supports remote upload unless they are integrated with the host system, in this case Amatisoft.

Also, Asterisk has its own live CD at their website http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/asterisknow ,  but I am stuck.

Could someone bridge the gap between [Brian's post](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0) and mine, i.e., fulfilling my objective with my equipments such as the Huawei e1731 Datacard and the BSNL SIM card using the wisdom from Brian's post?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to achieve this same goal recently and the simplest solution was to access the device via a combination of an Arduino and SEEED Studio GPRS shield.  This gave lower level access to the hardware and was able to ensure I was sending pure AT commands.

With this I was also able to initiate calls, send SMS messages, etc all from a Fedora system.

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0

Comment: Thanks. At least you were successful in an endeavour which is similar to that of mine. So I will give you a positive review for your intent to help. Will you please rate my question?

Comment: The matter appears possible via an OS specifically for the purpose. I tried to understand the symbian OS, but can find resources. I then reached android. I have posted a question: Access and control mobile phones, dongles and sim cards via Android OS in a Linux LVM in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013805/access-and-control-mobile-phones-dongles-and-sim-cards-via-android-os-in-a-linu